# How can I run Selenium Webdriver test case using ChromeDriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have done this

```
File file = new File("path\\to\\chrome driver");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Totally I have 5 testcases to test. But when testing only 2 or 3 test cases are running and the remaining are not.
Then I got error as,

`[1207/104351:ERROR:ipc_sync_channel.cc(378)] Canceling pending sends
[1207/104351:ERROR:automation_proxy.cc(319)] Channel error in AutomationProxy.`

My test cases are in **java** and i'm trying this is **Windiws OS**
What is this how can I fix this?

Comment: Do you mean simultaneously? And I'm assuming this is Java?

Comment: Yes In Java. What do you mean by Simultaneously here (Running multiple test cases at the same time)?

Comment: Do all of the test cases eventually run? Or do only 2 or 3 of them run before failure

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with Chromedriver.Refer this link [Chromedriver Issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=159)

Comment: This is sort of what I was getting at...you could simply be starting the same server multiple times on the same thread (simultaneously)

Answer (score 0):

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:/chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver  driver = new ChromeDriver();

Download chromedriver.exe from internet.

Answer (score 0):

Set the path to the chrome.exe.